# how to make a new column if a condition is fulfilled?

Tags: r, math, division

I want to make a warning column to warn the user of database if a condition is fulfilled. I currently have data like this.

```
      item       stock_need     rto     doi
PRE 24DX4SX15G    200           4800     14
PLS 12RX10SX15G   240           2400     10
ADU 24PX200ML     700           4800      8
NIS 18PX40SX11G   200           3600      4
REF 500GX12D      200           2400     20
```

i want to make a new column to warn the database user, if the doi less than 14 days AND rto/doi<= stock_need. So the output will be looked like this.

```
      item       stock_need     rto     doi    rto/doi    warn
PRE 24DX4SX15G    200           4800     14    
PLS 12RX10SX15G   240           2400     10      240    order now
ADU 24PX200ML     700           4800      8      600    order now
NIS 18PX40SX11G   200           3600      4      900
REF 500GX12D      200           2400     20
```

how to done this condition? Thanx so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored in a dataframe df:

```
warnIdx <- (df$doi < 14) & (df$rto/df$doi <= df$stock_need) # find rows fulfilling both conditions
df$warn <- NA_character_ #add a character column
df$warn[warnIdx] <- "order now" #replace tha NAs with "order now" in said rows
```